# How to validate a reactive form on submit?

Tags: angular, forms, validation, ionic3, angular-reactive-forms

I am using a reactive form for my application i want to validate the form on submit but i am not able to do that. Here is my code can anyone let me know what i am doing wrong or missing.

This is my form Builder

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPage, NavController, NavParams,ViewController,LoadingController, Events,AlertController } from 'ionic-angular';
import {Validators, FormBuilder, FormGroup, FormControl } from '@angular/forms';
import { MyinfoService} from '../../../../providers/app-services/myinfo/myinfo.service';

private formBuilder: FormBuilder) {
      this.licenseinfo = navParams.get('licenseinfo');
      this.startDate = this.licenseinfo.dlIssued_date;
      this.expiryDate= this.licenseinfo.dlExpiry_date;
      console.log(this.startDate);
      this.todo = this.formBuilder.group({
        issued_state  : ['', Validators.required],
        license_no    : ['', Validators.required],
        name          : ['', Validators.required],
        status        : ['Pending'],
        issued_date   : ['',Validators.required],
        expiry_date   : ['',Validators.required],
        address_line1 : ['',Validators.required],
        address_line2 : [''],
        city          : ['',Validators.required],
        zipcode: ['',Validators.required],
        state  : ['',Validators.required],
        employee_id   : ['']
      });
    }
```

This is my form

```
<ion-header>

    <ion-navbar>
      <ion-buttons start>
        <button ion-button (click)="dismiss()">Close</button>
      </ion-buttons>
      <ion-title>License Info Edit</ion-title>
    </ion-navbar>

  </ion-header>


  <ion-content padding>  
    <form [formGroup]="todo" (ngSubmit)="saveMyinfoLicenseinfo()">
      <ion-item>
        <ion-label stacked class="requiredLabel"> State Issued By</ion-label>
        <ion-input value="{{licenseinfo.issued_state}}" formControlName="issued_state"></ion-input>
      </ion-item> 

      <ion-item>
        <ion-label stacked class="requiredLabel">Driver Lic. No</ion-label>
        <ion-input type="text" value="{{licenseinfo.driver_lic_no}}" formControlName="license_no"></ion-input>
      </ion-item>

      <ion-item>
        <ion-label stacked class="requiredLabel">Name on DL</ion-label>
        <ion-input value="{{licenseinfo.name}}" formControlName="name"></ion-input>
      </ion-item>

      <ion-item>
        <ion-label stacked class="requiredLabel">Date Issued</ion-label>
        <ion-datetime displayFormat="MMM DD, YYYY" pickerFormat="DD MMM YYYY" formControlName="issued_date" [(ngModel)]="startDate" ></ion-datetime>
      </ion-item>

      <ion-item>
        <ion-label stacked class="requiredLabel">Expiry Date</ion-label>
        <ion-datetime displayFormat="MMM DD, YYYY" pickerFormat="DD MMM YYYY" formControlName="expiry_date" [(ngModel)]="expiryDate" ></ion-datetime>
      </ion-item>

      <ion-item>
          <ion-label stacked class="requiredLabel">Address Line1</ion-label>
          <ion-input value="{{licenseinfo.address_line1}}" formControlName="address_line1"></ion-input>
        </ion-item>

      <ion-item>
          <ion-label stacked >Address Line2</ion-label>
          <ion-input value="{{licenseinfo.address_line2}}" formControlName="address_line2"></ion-input>
        </ion-item>
      <ion-item>
          <ion-label stacked class="requiredLabel">City</ion-label>
          <ion-input value="{{licenseinfo.city}}" formControlName="city"></ion-input>
        </ion-item>

      <ion-item>
          <ion-label stacked class="requiredLabel">State</ion-label>
          <ion-input value="{{licenseinfo.issued_state}}" formControlName="issued_state"></ion-input>
        </ion-item>

        <ion-item>
          <ion-label stacked class="requiredLabel">Zipcode</ion-label>
          <ion-input value="{{licenseinfo.zipcode}}" formControlName="zipcode"></ion-input>
        </ion-item>

      <ion-input value="{{employee_id}}" formControlName="employee_id" hidden></ion-input>
      <ion-row>
        <ion-col>
          <button ion-button type="button" color="dark" outline block margin-top (click)="dismiss()">Cancel</button>
        </ion-col>
        <ion-col>
          <button ion-button type="submit" color="dark" margin-top block>Save</button>
        </ion-col>
      </ion-row>
    </form>
  </ion-content>
```

This is my on Submit code:

```
saveMyinfoLicenseinfo(){
    if(this.todo.valid){
    let loading = this.loadingCtrl.create({});
    loading.present();
    this.myinfoService.saveLicenseDetails(this.todo.value).subscribe(data => {
      loading.dismiss();        
        if(data.isSuccessful){
          this.viewCtrl.dismiss(true);
        }
        else
          this.viewCtrl.dismiss(false);
      });
      this.submitted = true;
    }
    else{
      this.validateAllFields(this.todo);
    }
}
validateAllFields(formGroup: FormGroup) {         
  Object.keys(formGroup.controls).forEach(field => {  
      const control = formGroup.get(field);            
      if (control instanceof FormControl) {             
          control.markAsTouched({ onlySelf: true });
          console.log(3);
      } else if (control instanceof FormGroup) {        
          this.validateAllFields(control);  
          console.log(this.validateAllFields(control));
      }
  });
}
```

so i am calling the onsubmit on to this function and if the form is not valid then i am trying to make all the feilds as touched but the color of the feilds is not changing even after submit. Can i know is this the right way to go? or Is there a better way of doing it?

Comment: I don't see anything in the HTML that would cause a colour change when a field becomes touched.  Is this in the external CSS file?

Comment: no, I thought the default validation for the fields using the form builder validation will be used. Normally when the fields are touched there will be a validation so i want to manually make all the fields touched.

Comment: Show us your imports

Comment: `import { Component } from '@angular/core';

import { IonicPage, NavController, NavParams,ViewController,LoadingController, Events,AlertController } from 'ionic-angular';

import {Validators, FormBuilder, FormGroup, FormControl } from '@angular/forms';

import { MyinfoService} from '../../../../providers/app-services/myinfo/myinfo.service';
/**` @Exterminator

Comment: If I understand correctly, when validation fails, you call the `validateAllFields` method on the form, which appears to iterate over all the `FormControl`s, “touch” them, and log `3` to the console each time.  What's your intended result of calling this method?

Comment: When the FormControls are touched i want it to validate the fields and change the color of the field to red. @AlexPeters 
Generally The form is validated when the fields are touched or dirty. Now i want to validate they are not touched but when the form is submitted

Answer (score 0):

You have defined the validators the wrong way, check the official documentation it will help you [Form Validation](https://angular.io/guide/form-validation#adding-to-reactive-forms)

The correct way to do it is this:

```
this.heroForm = new FormGroup({
  'name': new FormControl(this.hero.name, [
    Validators.required,
    Validators.minLength(4),
    forbiddenNameValidator(/bob/i) // <-- Here's how you pass in the custom validator.
  ]),
  'alterEgo': new FormControl(this.hero.alterEgo),
  'power': new FormControl(this.hero.power, Validators.required)
});
```

Comment: I think that's, not a problem because we can use form builders for validating the forms instead of form Groups as specified in the Documentation. The problem is that validation is not initiating on dynamic Touch of the fields.

Answer (score 0):

Your invalid form fields don't change colour on submit because you don't appear to have set up any CSS (or CSS classes) for fields with invalid values.

Take a look at the [Reactive form validation](https://angular.io/guide/form-validation#reactive-form-validation) section of the Angular docs for examples on:

1. how to get information on the validity of each field in the template, and
2. how to add HTML to show errors alongside/within the form (if desired)

[The `ngClass` directive](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#ngClass) might be very helpful in dynamically assigning a specific class to an invalid form field.  You can then code appropriate CSS in the accompanying CSS file, or utilise any classes that Ionic might provide specifically for invalid form entries.

Answer (score 0):

try with this Html code.

```
<form [formGroup]="todo" #f="ngForm" (ngSubmit)='saveMyinfoLicenseinfo()' novalidate>

        <ion-item class="Your css class">
            <ion-input type="text"  formControlName="name"></ion-input>
        </ion-item>
        <div *ngIf="f.submitted && todo.controls.name.errors?.required" class="Error class ">Please enter Name</div>            


        <ion-item>
            <button ion-button outline>GO</button>
        </ion-item>

</form>
```